# Non-orthogonal frames

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

Fix $4$-dimensional Minkowskian spacetime $(\mathbb{R}^4, \eta)$. As in my previous posts, a reference frame is then simply a choice of basis vectors $\{e_{\mu}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\{e_0\}$ is timelike, while $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ are spacelike. Then every $4$-vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^4$ can be uniquely written as

$$v = te_0 + xe_{1} + ye_{2} + ze_{3}\rightarrow [v] = \begin{pmatrix} t \\\ x\\\ y\\\ z\end{pmatrix}$$

However, the choice of basis vectors is not necessilarly orthogonal. Therefore, although the physics that the vector signifies should not change, i.e its length and direction remain invariant, the numeric value of $\eta(v, v)$ might change under different choices of basis vectors. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Therefore, although the physics that the vector signifies should not change, i.e its length and direction remain invariant, the numeric value of $\eta(v, v)$ might change under different choices of basis vectors. Is this right?

This is not right. The notation
$$
\eta(v_1 - v_2, v_1 - v_2)
$$
stands for the squared distance (or "space-time interval") between the two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ in [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Minkowski_metric).

So your $\eta(v,v)$ stands for the space-time interval ("squared distance") from the origin to $v$. In special relativity, by construction/definition, this distance can not depend on your choice of coordinates.

The precise form of the metric matrix
$$
\eta_{\mu,\nu}=\eta(\hat e_\mu, \hat e_\nu)
$$
might change with the basis, but the distance from the origin to $v$ will not change.

Answer (score 1):

The basis does not necessarily have to be orthogonal, correct. For that matter you don't have to choose 3 space like and 1 time like vector. You just need 4 independent vectors. But note that the form of the metric $\eta$ will depend on how the coordinates are chosen. That is, the metric itself (the underlying geometry) is coordinate independent, but when describing it with coordinates some coordinates are easier then others. The usual $-dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ form is for orthonormal $(t, x, y, z)$.

Comment: Since spacetime is $(3,1)$ dimensional doesn't that mean there is a maximum of 3 mutually linear independent spacelike vectors, requiring the 4th of the set to be timelike?

Comment: It is possible to use light like vectors as some of the basis vectors for coordinates

Answer (score 1):

> However, the choice of basis vectors is not necessilarly orthogonal.
> Therefore, although the physics that the vector signifies should not
> change, i.e its length and direction remain invariant, the numeric
> value of η(v,v)  might change under different choices of basis
> vectors. Is this right?

The answer is no. Once you have a metric tensor that describes your spacetime, any other metric tensor will be related to this metric tensor in such a way that the quantity $\eta(u,v)$ is the same. For example, if you write out $\eta$ as a matrix,
\begin{align}
\eta(u,v)=u^T\cdot\eta\cdot v,
\end{align}
then $\eta$ transforms as follows under a basis transformation.
\begin{align}
u&\mapsto A\cdot u\\
v&\mapsto A\cdot v\\
\eta&\mapsto A\cdot\eta\cdot A^T
\end{align}
where $A^TA=1\hspace{-3.3pt}1$, i.e. $A$ is orthogonal.